# Vim or sed : Replace character(s) within a pattern

Tags: vim, sed, replace

I wanted to replace underscores with hyphens in all places where the character('_') is preceded and following by uppercase letters e.g. QWQW_IOIO, OP_FD_GF_JK, TRT_JKJ, etc. The replacement is needed throughout one document.

I tried to replace this in vim using:
`:%s/[A-Z]_[A-Z]/[A-Z]-[A-Z]/g`
But that resulted in `QWQW_IOIO` with `QWQ[A-Z]-[A-Z]OIO`  :(

I tried using a sed command:
`sed -i '/[A-Z]_[A-Z]/ s/_/-/g' ./file_name`
This resulted in replacement over the whole line. e.g.

`QWQW_IOIO variable may contain '_' or '-'` line was replaced by

`QWQW-IOIO variable may contain '-' or '-'`

Comment: The "capture groups" in the answer below are similar to what is available in `sed` (excepting the `\v` and `\u` stuff). See http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-3 for a gentle intro . Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea with your first vim approach. But you need to use a capturing group to remember what character was found in the `[A-Z]` section. Those are nicely explained [here](http://vimregex.com/#backreferences) and under `:h /\1`. As a side note, I would recommend using `\u` instead of `[A-Z]`, since it is both shorter and faster. That means the solution you want is:

```
:%s/\(\u\)_\(\u\)/\1-\2/g
```

Or, if you would like to use the magic setting to make it more readable:

```
:%s/\v(\u)_(\u)/\1-\2/g
```

Another option would be to limit the part of the search that gets replaced with the `\zs` and `\ze` atoms:

```
:%s/\u\zs_\ze\u/-/g
```

This is the shortest solution I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want, assuming GNU sed.

```
sed -i -r -e 's/([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)/\1-\2/g' ./file_name
```

Explanation:

`-r` flag enables extended regex

`[A-Z]+` is "one or more uppercase letters"

`()` groups a pattern together and creates a numbered memorized match

`\1`, `\2` put those memorized matches in the replacement.

So basically this finds a chunk of uppercase letters followed by an underscore, followed by another chunk of uppercase letters, memorizes only the letter chunks as 2 groups,

```
([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)
```

Then it replays those groups, but with a hyphen in between instead of an underscore.

```
\1-\2
```

The `g` flag at the end says to do this even if the pattern shows up multiple times on one line.

Note that this falls apart a little in this case:

```
QWQW_IOIO_ABAB
```

Because it matches the first time, but not the second; the second part won't match because IOIO was consumed by the first match. So that would result in

```
QWQW-IOIO_ABAB
```

This version drops the `+` so it only matches one uppercase letter, and won't break in the same way:

```
sed -i -r -e 's/([A-Z])_([A-Z])/\1-\2/g'
```

It still has a small flaw, if you have a string like this:

```
A_B_C
```

Same issue as before, just one letter now instead of multiple.